# Jcrop Large Image True Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jcrop

I'm having a problem using **jCrop**...

If I upload a image, for example, 1024x768, he will get most of my browser.
So what I did in order to turn around?

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;(Just examples!)">
<img> bla bla
</div>
```

And now it's working, but now, I need the real size of the image.
basically, I have a div that contains the image that I want to crop, but I want the true size of them..

Some things I've already attempted:

Tried to make a `div` with `overflow:scroll`, the problem was, while I was cropping, I wanted, while cropping, when I reach the limits of the div, he scrolls while I was going on..

Some help will be useful. (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your post. What do you mean by "If I upload a image, for example, 1024x768, he will get most of my browser"?

Comment: If i upload an image with size of 1024x760, for example, he will be to bigger for my browser in order to crop , understand? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than setting the dimensions of your image in CSS, jcrop has `boxWidth` and `boxHeight` parameters for this purpose.

Using these parameters, jcrop will resize the image to fit in the specified box size, but it will still output values relative to the true size.

You can set them like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({ boxWidth: 300, boxHeight: 300 });
});
```

See here for more information: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Sizing_Issues.html

Comment: How would this work for larger images that you want re-sizing (responsive) on smaller screens?

Comment: @Ciwan For that circumstance, I would use the `trueSize` parameter approach instead. See here: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Sizing_Issues.html